# nginx is causing errors with user agent

Tags: nginx, user-agent

My site is trying to use user agents for a responsive design. The problem I'm having is that the user agents aren't registering correctly. Some desktops are rendering mobile and some phones/tablets are rendering the full site.

Here is the kicker, on the test site, it works fine. That is, without interacting with nginx. I tried hooking the test site into nginx and had the same issues. I tied into apache, and everything worked fine.

Does anyone have any idea why nginx would be having this issue? Any ideas would be helpful so that I can have someone look into it for me.

Thank you

Comment: Please post your `.conf` files

Comment: From the site itself or nginx?

Comment: Both, it will give us an idea of what you are attempting to do.

Comment: I was able to get it fixed. Thanks for the response though. It was an error in the config

Comment: I'm not sure how to mark this as closed or solved or whatever, so someone can feel free to do it if need be

Comment: You should post the answer so people will know how you fixed it in the future.